# Custom PS1 enabled after using sudo su

Tags: linux, centos

I set a script into my .bash_profile non root account on my centos linux machine to change my PS1 after sudo su but because sudo su is actually make a new session the script of course stops and my PS1 remain the same despite the fact my .bash_profile is saying to change it, nothing wrong here but is there any method to execute a command(in my case to change my PS1) after sudo su ? I tried to put the script also into .bashrc and same.

Answer (score 4):

Stacking `sudo` and `su` makes for a mess in my opinion.

For me the most reliable way to create the correct environment for root, that includes setting of the correct PATH and other settings from the  relevant files from `/root/` is **`sudo -i`**

Please read the manual pages [`man su`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/su) and [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) because there heaps of subtleties with PATH and other session and environment variables getting changed or not as the  default or by specific switches.

Please note the difference between  `su -` and `su` and for instance the fact that typically sudo is configured in `/etc/sudoers` to suppress certain environment variables ...

[This table](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells) (and the whole article) gives some of differences of what at first glance seem to be similar commands:

```
                                     corrupted by user's 
        HOME=/root  uses root's PATH     env vars
sudo -i     Y       Y[2]                 N
sudo -s     N       Y[2]                 Y
sudo bash   N       Y[2]                 Y
sudo su     Y       N[1]                 Y


[1] PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
    probably set by /etc/environment
[2] PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for that link, will be useful for a course I teach

Comment: I tried also with sudo -i instead of sudo su and the PS1 switch to default(root) again.